# Get only the imediate parent, not all path, using placeholders

Tags: sass, scss-mixins

I have the following sass:

```
%slider {
  .c-slider {
    $parent: &;
    &--thumb {
     #{$parent}__item{
       margin:0;
     }
    }
  }
}
.l-cap {
  @extend %slider;
}
```

and I get:

```
 .l-cap .c-slider--thumb .l-cap .c-slider__item {margin: 0; }
```

But I want to obtain:

```
.l-cap .c-slider--thumb .c-slider__item {margin: 0; }
```

I need for the second to just get the immediate parent. I tried @at-root but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use this approach. `&` is a sass list of lists referencing to all the parent elements for the current selector, so you can use all the list functions on `&` and easily get the nth child of `&` of your choice (in this case de second one):

```
%slider {
  .c-slider {

    // Get just the second selector
    $parent : nth(nth(&, 1), 2);

    // Output
    &--thumb #{$parent}__item{
      margin:0;
    }

  }
}

.l-cap {
  @extend %slider;
}
```

Will output:

```
.l-cap .c-slider--thumb .c-slider__item {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

That's the only way how to achieve it

```
%slider {
  .c-slider {
    &--thumb {
     .c-slider__item{
        margin:0;
      }
    }
  }
}

.l-cap {
  @extend %slider;
}
```

result will be

```
.l-cap .c-slider--thumb .c-slider__item {
  margin: 0;
}
```

and for more complex nesting you can use @at-root

```
.grand-parent {
  .parent {
    @at-root .myDiv {
      color: blue; 
    }
  }
}
```

result will be

```
.myDiv {
  color: blue;
}
```